# Trying to publish local android library module to Artifactory

Tags: android, gradle, artifactory

I created a new Android library module inside of my project as a test library. It's a simple module with one class with one static method that returns a string. I have Artifactory server running locally and want to push my Android lib/module to it. I generated the Gradle script and gradle properties from Artifactory web interface. My build.gradle in my testLib module now looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'

}

/////

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-release'
            credentials {
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        //Check for the latest version here: http://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.1.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"   //The base Artifactory URL if not overridden by the publisher/resolver
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
}
```

After I added that, I ran the `./gradlew artifactoryPublish` command. It says BUILD SUCCESSFUL. I then go to artifactory web app to the repository browser and I look under `libs-release-local` and it has an artifact count of 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never worked with local AARs before, but I used this guy to help figure out how this stuff works.  Maybe it'll help you? https://github.com/blundell/release-android-library

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I haven't been able to use that repo to my advantage... =(

Answer (score 4):

Found a working example here: http://jeroenmols.github.io/blog/2015/08/06/artifactory/

Comment: url can become unavailable, its better to show the main solution is sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the `maven-publish` plugin in the `build.gradle` file of your Android module and add a `publishing { ... }` block in there which makes the module publishable. Secondly, you need to specify in the `artifactory { ... }` block of your project's root-level `build.gradle` file what is to be published.

See this StackOverflow thread for an example of how to do this for an Android library project:

[Gradle Artifactory Plugin - How to publish artifacts from multiple modules in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851251)