# Gradle Artifactory Plugin - How to publish artifacts from multiple modules in a project?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, artifactory, maven-publish

I have a project which has a `SharedCode` (Java) module and secondly an `Android` (Android library) module which depends on the `SharedCode` module. I want to publish a `jar` artifact from the `SharedCode` module and an `aar` artifact from the `Android` module. I can't figure out how to compose my `build.gradle` files so that both modules publish to Artifactory when the `artifactoryPublish` task is run. At the moment only the `SharedCode` module publishes its artifact to Artifactory.

My `build.gradle` files are as below. Note that the `maven-publish` aspect of my `build.gradle` files appears to be correct because when I run the `publishToMavenLocal` task I see the artifacts from both modules in my local Maven folder (i.e. `'~/.m2/repository'`).

Firstly, the `build.gradle` file in my `SharedCode` module is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'

group = "${projectGroupId}"
version = "${projectVersionName}"

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        SharedCode(MavenPublication) {
            groupId "${projectGroupId}"
            artifactId 'SharedCode'
            version "${projectVersionName}"
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_url}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_username}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
        defaults {
            publications('SharedCode')
            publishArtifacts = true
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly, the `build.gradle` file in my `Android` module is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'

group = "${projectGroupId}"
version = "${projectVersionName}"

android {
    // android stuff here...
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':SharedCode')
}

publishing {
    publications {
        Android(MavenPublication) {
            groupId "${projectGroupId}"
            artifactId 'Android'
            version "${projectVersionName}"
            artifact "$buildDir/outputs/aar/Android-release.aar"
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_url}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_username}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
        defaults {
            publications('Android')
            publishArtifacts = true
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the `artifactoryPublish` task at the root, project level or at the `SharedCode` module level then I see output as follows:

```
18:23:38: Executing external task 'artifactoryPublish'...
Publication named 'SharedCode' does not exist for project ':Android' in task ':Android:artifactoryPublish'.
:SharedCode:generatePomFileForSharedCodePublication
:SharedCode:artifactoryPublish
Deploying artifact: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/mycompany/sdk/SharedCode/0.0.2/SharedCode-0.0.2.jar
Deploying artifact: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/mycompany/sdk/SharedCode/0.0.2/SharedCode-0.0.2.pom
Deploying build descriptor to: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/build Build successfully deployed.
Browse it in Artifactory under http://localhost:8081/artifactory/webapp/builds/client-sdk/1457375019604

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Note that only the `SharedCode` artifact is published in this case.

If I run the `artifactoryPublish` task at the `Android` module level, then I see output as follows:

```
18:25:25: Executing external task 'artifactoryPublish'...
Publication named 'SharedCode' does not exist for project ':Android' in task ':Android:artifactoryPublish'.
:Android:artifactoryPublish
Deploying build descriptor to: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/build
Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under http://localhost:8081/artifactory/webapp/builds/client-sdk/1457375127269

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Note that no artifacts are published in this case.

Comment: What is the folder structure of your modules? Do you have both Shared and Android under a third Root folder? Can you show your settings.gradle as well please?

Comment: Yes, I have a root folder which has a project-level `build.gradle` file which has nothing substantial in it right now other than classpath declarations. And under that folder I have an `Android` and a `SharedCode` folder which represent an Android library and a Java module respectively. The `build.gradle` files for these two modules are as in my question above. (Thanks for your help btw @RaGe. Really appreciate it.)

Comment: My `settings.gradle` file has these three lines: (1) `rootProject.name = 'client-sdk'`; (2) `include ':Android'`; (3) `include ':SharedCode'`.

Comment: Adil, could you post a full working (after you took the advice from the accepted answer) to the end of your question?  (for us future reader newbies?). Thanks.

Comment: @granadaCoder, I posted a working solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36045329/1071320) answer but note that I later abandoned the `com.jfrog.artifactory` plugin in favour of the standard `maven-publish` plugin for Java library modules and the `digital.wup.android-maven-publish` plugin for Android library modules. See my comments in the answer that I've linked to. For an example of the `digital.wup.android-maven-publish` plugin, see the `build.gradle` files in [this](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/quran-sdk) repository.

Comment: Thanks for the breadcrumb.

Comment: I also had to apply the `maven-publish` plugin in the root `build.gradle` to get it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by artifactory multi-project examples on their github repo, it would seem that only the root project needs to have an `artifactory{...}` configuration section as opposed to in every sub-project as you have done.

Moreover when you declare `publications('SharedCode')` in the root project, artifactory plugin seems to be looking for a publication called `sharedCode` in every subproject.

I would try:

- Remove the `artifactory{...}` section from the android build.gradle
- Rename the android publication to `sharedCode` as well (or something more generic in both projects)

Comment: So I've moved the `artifactory{...}` section out from the `Android` and `SharedCode` modules and up into the project-level `build.gradle` file as follows: `artifactory { publish { publications('SharedCode', 'Android') } }`. This seems to be the right thing to do. But when I run the `artifactoryPublish` task now I get the following two error messages: (1) `Publication named 'SharedCode' does not exist for project ':' in task ':artifactoryPublish'.` (2) `Publication named 'Android' does not exist for project ':' in task ':artifactoryPublish'.` Oh and no artifacts are published to Artifactory.

Comment: Next step I guess is to figure out how to make the `artifactoryPublish` task aware of the `SharedCode` and `Android` modules.

Comment: You need to add something like artifactory.skip=true in the root project. One of the example projects had it.

Comment: No luck :-( Tried adding `artifactory { defaults { skip = true } }` as well as `artifactoryPublish { skip = true }` but still getting the same "Publication named ... does not exist for project ..." error messages as before.

Comment: Can you post your current root build.gradle to a github gist?

Comment: Small gain today: got Artifactory publishing working by removing the `com.jfrog.artifactory` plugin and instead using the `publishing { repositories { maven { ... } } }` construct from the `maven-publish` plugin in each of my `Android/build.gradle` and `SharedCode/build.gradle` files. And then to use the `publish` Gradle task.

Comment: so you're effectively treating artifactory as a maven repo? Good to know that this works. I don't have ready access to an artifactory instance right now, I didn't get a change to test this yet. Will look into it later tonight.

Comment: I'm having to resort to this until I can figure out how to get the Gradle Artifactory plugin to work :-( This does work though. I kicked off a local Artifactory instance on my machine and was able to upload the artifacts.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue. Once I add `artifactoryPublish.skip=true` to the root build.gradle, the sub-projects are able to publish their publications to Artifactory just fine. See [git repo here](https://github.com/foragerr/SO-35851251-Multiproject-Artifactory-Publish). Running `gradle artifactoryPublish` from the root project results in: http://i.imgur.com/awdazUo.png

Comment: So strange... I don't know how this is working for you. I checked out the project that you created and when I run any Gradle task I see this output in the console: (1) `Publication named 'JavaPublication' does not exist for project ':subB' in task ':subB:artifactoryPublish'.` (2) `Publication named 'someOtherName' does not exist for project ':subA' in task ':subA:artifactoryPublish'.` Any ideas??

Comment: Interestingly... running the `artifactoryPublish` Gradle task _does_ publish the `foo` and `bar`artifacts to Artifactory despite the error messages in the console (see previous comment)!

Comment: are those warning or errors? Do they break the build? What it says is true, those publications do not exist on all sub projects, but that shouldn't be a problem. OR - you could name the publications in both projects the same and you wont get even that message.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this @RaGe. I've marked your answer as the accepted answer and awarded you the bounty. Although I still haven't managed to get the artifact from the Android library to publish to Artifactory I'll investigate this further and raise a separate, clearer question about this.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** As of version `4.6.0` of the [com.jfrog.artifactory](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory) Gradle plugin, publishing artifacts in a multi-module project just does not work. From personal experience, you're best just abandoning this plugin and using the standard [maven-publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) plugin for both Java library modules and Android library modules.

**--- What follows below is my original answer before I posted the above update ---**

So I've finally got this all working! Special thanks to @RaGe for helping me along the way. The key points to note are that the `artifactory` block needs to be in the project's root-level `build.gradle` file and not in the `build.gradle` file of the individual modules. Also, you need to add `artifactoryPublish.skip=true` to the project's root-level `build.gradle` file. See this GitHub repo for a full-on yet minimal-as-possible example:

https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/SO-35851251-Multiproject-Artifactory-Publish

In case the link ever stops working I'll paste the contents of the `build.gradle` files here also. Firstly, the project's root-level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    group = "${projectGroupName}"
    version = "${projectVersionName}"
}

artifactoryPublish.skip=true

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_url}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_username}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
        defaults {
        publications('SomePublication')
            publishArtifacts = true
            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.8'
}
```

Secondly, the `build.gradle` file of the `Android` module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode Integer.parseInt("${projectVersionCode}")
        versionName "${projectVersionName}"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':SharedCode')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        SomePublication(MavenPublication) {
            artifact "$buildDir/outputs/aar/Android-release.aar"

            //The publication doesn't know about our dependencies, so we have to manually add them to the pom
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                //Iterate over the compile dependencies (we don't want the test ones), adding a <dependency> node for each
                configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thirdly and finally, the `build.gradle` file of the `SharedCode` (Java) module:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        SomePublication(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

That's it!

Comment: I'm using version `4.4.14` of the plugin and I can confirm that I no longer need the hack of adding the `artifactory {...}` block in the project's root level `build.gradle` file. The `publishing {...}` and `artifactory {...}` blocks can be added separately in each of the modules of the project that are to publish artifacts.

Comment: Is it possible to publish an apk to the artifactory? I have a project with 2 modules. One is a library and other one is an application.

Comment: DineshKumar, I'm guessing by application you mean Android application, i.e. an apk file. I haven't tried it but it certainly should be possible to PUT your apk file to Artifactory with Gradle. Bear in mind that you won't want to publish your apk as a Maven artifact (i.e. with a pom file etc) since that only makes sense for libraries.

Comment: **Update:** As of version `4.6.0` of the `com.jfrog.artifactory` Gradle plugin publishing artifacts in a multi-module project just does not work. From personal experience you're best just abandoning this plugin and using the standard `maven-publish` plugin for Java library modules and the `digital.wup.android-maven-publish` plugin for Android library modules.

Comment: You are right. I am trying to upload an apk along with an aar. I have partially succeeded. What am facing is, if the apk gets uploaded, aar doesnt and vice-versa.After adding the artifactory closure in the root gradle file, the log shows deploying artifacts for both. However, in case of library it just has an empty folder and a pom file and the apk gets uploaded successfully. Any idea about this?

Comment: I somehow found a solution to upload both `aar` and a `apk` file.Its working for me and am using version 4.2.0. Earlier I was using 3.1.2 and it didnt work.

Comment: Okay. Good stuff. I had success with version `4.5.4` of the `com.jfrog.artifactory` plugin but no luck with later versions. I've now abandoned using this plugin in favour of using the `digital.wup.android-maven-publish` and `maven-publish` plugins with a `publishing { publications { ... } repositories { ... } }` block in each of my `build.gradle` files.

Comment: **Update:** The [digital.wup.android-maven-publish](https://github.com/wupdigital/android-maven-publish) Gradle plugin has been deprecated since the [maven-publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) Gradle plugin is now supported by the Android Gradle plugin. See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin) for a short guide on how to use the `maven-publish` to publish an Android application or Android library.

Answer (score 3):

Version 4.2.0 of the Gradle Artifactory Plugin was released last week and added multiple Artifactory repositories deployment. Now you can simply define an artifactory closure with a different repository for different modules of the project.

Comment: We confirm that this is an issue started from 4.4.9 of the Gradle Artifactory Plugin, Jira ticket: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/GAP-272.

Comment: Fixed plugin version has been released and an example project  - [gradle-example-multi-repos](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/4) has been added.

Comment: I'm using version `4.4.14` of the plugin and I can confirm that I no longer need the hack of adding the `artifactory {...}` block in the project's root level `build.gradle` file. The `publishing {...}` and `artifactory {...}` blocks can be added separately in each of the modules of the project that are to publish artifacts.

Comment: Which gradle command are you using? **gradle clean build artifactoryPublish** is not publishing the android modules (only the java modules).