# Gradle Artifactory Plugin - looking for example of publishing artifacts from multiple modules in a project?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, artifactory, maven-publish

(I typed up a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851251) a couple of days ago but it's pretty involved so I can imagine it might not get an answer.)

Can anyone point me to an example of the Gradle Artifactory Plugin which publishes artifacts from multiple modules in a project? I've had a look online but could not find any examples. It surely must be possible! If someone can point me to an example of a project that contains an Android library module that would be a huge bonus!

Comment: Which maven plugin are you using?

Comment: `maven-publish`... this seems to be the preferred plugin to use with the `com.jfrog.artifactory` plugin from the [examples](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/4) that I've seen online so far. Just can't find an example of a multi-module project. My project consists of two modules: one which applies the `com.android.library` plugin and one which applies the `java` plugin.

Comment: isn't this example: https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/4/gradle-example a multi-module example? There is a subproject in the main project.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @RaGe. I think I did come across this earlier but couldn't make head and tails of it. Certainly not straightforward, easy-to-follow and well-explained example. Will download it and play around with it and try make sense of what it's doing, what it's publishing etc.

Comment: @RaGe... hmm, just noticed it's using the `maven` plugin rather than the `maven-publish` plugin. This example might be more useful for me: https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/4/gradle-example-publish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jfrog's github repository has some examples:

1. [Artifactory publishing in a java multi-project, using `maven` plugin](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/4/gradle-example)
2. [Artifactory publishing in a java multi-project, using `maven-publish` plugin](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/4/gradle-example-publish)
3. [Artifactory publishing for an android (aar) project](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/4/gradle-android-aar)

There isn't an example for multi-project that includes android, but that should follow easily from the above examples.

Comment: Thanks RaGe. I'll look into these and try them out when I'm back at work next week.